# How to insert value from textbox and button to each row in certain column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview with 4 columns. columns 1 to 2 bound to database and 3 to 4 is containing label. for input  I have 2 textbox (textbox1 and texbox2)and 1 button (button1).

my question is:-

1. the gridview dataset is generated after I retrieve data from database (with another input). so can I insert value using textbox1 and textbox2 to each row in column 3 and column 4 after I click button1.
2. if can be insert, how can i generate it?

I've been trying many examples/ solutions but failed.

thank you.

Comment: can you please post code what you have tried

Comment: please post what you have done.

Comment: Please post the code what you have tried till now. Do you need to save that data to database then wanted to show in `Gridview` or on button click it will just add to `Gridview`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to put some code where your button is with the textbox1 address.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // your simple button function
    {
       textbox_output.Text = text_you_wish;
    }
```

its kind of hard to understand what do you mean without posting a code or a picture of the code...